# Differences between new String and Bytes.toString

Tags: string, byte

I am using hbase utility `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes` 
I generated a an array of Bytes from a string (in a example in Scala):

`val bytes = Bytes.toBytes("test")`

and want to convert back in String.

What is the difference between `new String(bytes,"UTF-8")`  and `Bytes.toString(bytes)`

They both works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess that you are talking about https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html, basically nothing: `Bytes.toString` will call `new String`, except if the array is empty. You can see the method called [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/bb3d9ccd489fb64e3cb2020583935a393382a678/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.java#L586):

```
public static String toString(final byte [] b, int off, int len) {
    if (b == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (len == 0) {
      return "";
    }
    return new String(b, off, len, UTF8_CHARSET);
}
```

For the future, please mention any libraries you are using in the question (and the question is completely unrelated to Scala).

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I am gonna try to edit the question to be more understandable